# javafx akka dispatcher leaks

Tags: javafx, akka, actor

I have created an executor:

```
public class GUIExecutorService extends AbstractExecutorService {

@Override
public void shutdown() {

}

@Override
public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public boolean isShutdown() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isTerminated() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    Platform.runLater(command);
}
}
```

and configurator:

```
public class JavaFXEventThreadExecutorServiceConfigurator extends ExecutorServiceConfigurator {

public JavaFXEventThreadExecutorServiceConfigurator(Config config, DispatcherPrerequisites prerequisites) {
    super(config, prerequisites);
}

@Override
public ExecutorServiceFactory createExecutorServiceFactory(String id, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    return () -> new GUIExecutorService(); 
}    
}
```

and I did use it :

```
this.navigatorActor = getContext().actorOf(new Props(() -> new NavigatorActor(stage)).withDispatcher("javafx-dispatcher"), "navigator" );
```

But once I want to stop in the application using:

```
actorSystem.shutdown();
```

My program still executes.

Using last shutdown I hoped it should close all actor system.

Actor did not terminate.

What wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do a stacktrace (`jstack PID`) or use a profiler to see which thread-pool is still alive and kicking.

Comment: THanks Knrad, but I don't really understand what did it print:

Comment: As I can see: 
MapReduceApp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 running  and
NapReduceApp-scheduler-1 running

Answer (score 0):

You need to change return bool from true to false.

```
@Override
public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I simply threw away this lib and that all. And I am happy.